# Make python code blocks format their results as Org tables

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

## The context

In `#+BEGIN_SRC` code blocks whose language is `cpp` or `sh`, the tab character is used as a delimiter for cells when using the `:results table` header argument (see examples below)

```
#+begin_src cpp :results replace output table
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "a\ta\nbbbbb\tbbbbb" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| a     | a     |
| bbbbb | bbbbb |
```

```
#+begin_src sh :results replace output table
printf "%s\t%s\n" "a" "a" "bbbbbb" "bbbbbb"
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| a      | a      |
| bbbbbb | bbbbbb |
```

However, this same behavior is not present in `python` code blocks (see below)

```
#+begin_src python :results replace output table
print("a\ta\nbbbbb\tbbbbb")
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: a a
: bbbbb bbbbb
```

## The question

How can I make the output of `python` code blocks be displayed as Org tables. Isn't using those header arguments and make the output contain tab characters enough for the `#+RESULTS` to be formatted as an Org table?

Comment: I use `jupyter-python` and it formats as tables automatically. You can also do this manually with the `tabulate` package. I'm not sure how to do it with unchanged Org+Python.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can output formatted org tables by returning a list of lists as follows (notice no :results output):

```
#+begin_src python :results replace table
return (('a', 'a'), None, ('bbbbb', 'bbbbb'))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| a     | a     |
|-------+-------|
| bbbbb | bbbbb |
```

a None row creates a separator line.

Here are some other examples using `:results output`

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output table
print([['Number', 'Number * 10'], None, [1, 10], [2, 20]])
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| Number | Number * 10 |
|--------+-------------|
|      1 |          10 |
|      2 |          20 |
```

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results value table
return [['Number', 'Number * 10'], None, [1, 10], [2, 20]]
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| Number | Number * 10 |
|--------+-------------|
|      1 |          10 |
|      2 |          20 |
```

Note that when using `:results output`, a single `print` is included in  the `#+RESULTS` code block.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output table
for i in range(5):
  print([i, i**10])
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| 0 | 0 |
```